# Installing on a single hdd

Tags: kernel

I have a 250GB HDD with a partition for Windows 10. I am currently trying to install Ubuntu on the unused partition.How can this be achieved?

Comment: How much space do you have? `/home` should be a partition of it's own, as should `/`, and `swap`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all shrink your partition. You can do this with a tool like Gparted or use the Disk Manager that comes with Windows 10.

Get a USB and burn the [Ubuntu .iso](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) to it. Now boot from your live USB (you can change the boot order in your BIOS/UEFI or hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while clicking Restart on your Windows 10 Start Menu).

You will be given an option to install Ubuntu. Do that, and when you are shown the screen that says "Installation Type", click "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager".

The rest of the installation you just do normally. Good luck!